# HTML list is not displayed

Tags: css, html, list, html-lists

I'm making an editable and printable form in html, to generate documents like invoices and our terms and conditions. It's for a little business of mine. I thought I had it all correct, but...

HTML:

```
<h1>Artikel 1</h1>
Spotlight Student gaat akkoord met de levering van diensten voor de klant in de volgende vorm:<br><br>
<ul>
   <li>Gelegenheid: <span contenteditable>Evenement</span></li>
   <li>Datum: <span contenteditable>Datum van evenement</span></li>
   <li>Tijd: <span contenteditable>Tijd van aankomst</span></li>
   <li>Locatie: <span contenteditable>Adres Locatie</span></li>
   <li>Geleverde dienst: <span contenteditable>Overeengekomen dienst</span></li>                
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li { margin-left: 25px; list-style-type: square;}
```

When I was coding this part of the form, a list, it displayed perfectly when I opened it locally in Google Chrome: http://i77.photobucket.com/albums/j64/kippendrecht/listoffline_zpsabe5ff34.jpg

But when I had uploaded it to my webserver and viewed the page online, still in Google Chrome, all the mark up was gone: http://i77.photobucket.com/albums/j64/kippendrecht/listonline_zps5e3d8add.jpg

What went wrong?

Comment: You will need to provide more code than that. Are you sure you are calling the stylesheet correctly?

Comment: The rest of the page is displaying just fine, so the style sheet is working. It's just this little part, hence why I only showed this part. What more should I include?

Comment: Did you upload the CSS file along with the HTML? Is the reference to the CSS file in the HTML still correct? You can also try putting your CCS code inline inside the HTML file to help determine where the issue is.

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to update the CSS path from local to the remote server?

Comment: You may have overwriting you CSS on a previous line?

Comment: Thank for the suggestions, I already deleted everything in the path folder and re-uploaded all files. It's working locally, so I figured it would work online too...

Comment: This is the only li item in the css file.

Comment: Can you provide us a link to the live site?

Comment: I can't afpel, it's password protected. These forms are private. but your answer did the trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are only two possible causes for this problem:

1. The CSS file didn't get included properly.
2. You override the style, try using a more specific selector or eliminate the override.

The last one is more probable since the heading looks different, too.

Edit: Additionally, apply the `list-style-type` to the ul and make sure it has some padding if `list-style-position` is set to `outside` (Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aye2y/). This may be done by a CSS reset you only use online.

Comment: thanks! The <span contenteditable> messed up the css, it didn't inherit the style. And the style-postion: outside was also needed!

Comment: Thanks to afpel it's now working. It was all in the CSS coding.

The list, headers and text were all contained in a division, with the class selector .text. I used this to format the text. But the elements inside this div didn't inherit the style. So I made specific selectors:

    .text, .text span, .text div, .text li{ font-size: 14px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 16px; }

I also needed to add the style-position declaration:

    .text li { margin-left: 25px; list-style-position: outside}

Thanks!